# Function generic over Foldable and Data.Vector.Unboxed

Tags: haskell, vector

`Data.Vector.Unboxed` is not an instance of `Foldable`. What is the best way to write a function which works on instances of `Foldable` as well as on unboxed vectors? For example this version of `sum` works with lists and boxed vectors, but not unboxed:

```
sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
sum = Foldable.foldl' (+) 0
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking to implement a single polymorphic function which can fold a function over all three types ( Vector, Vector.Unboxed, and List ) ? And all of which presumably contain values having ``Unbox`` constraint as well?

Comment: @StephenDiehl Yes that's right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like something [mono-traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-0.4.0.3/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html) could do for you. F.e. it already contains a `sum` variant:

```
osum :: (MonoFoldable mono, Num (Element mono)) => mono -> Element mono
osum = ofoldl' (+) 0
```

Comment: Cool! Pity about the silly prefixed names though :-)